# IIS Removal of Server information header

Tags: rewrite, iis-8.5, asp-classic

I have written the following url rewrite module to remove server version information in response header.

```
    <rewrite>
      <outboundRules>        
         <rule name="Remove Server header">
           <match filterByTags="None" serverVariable="" pattern=".+" />
           <action type="Rewrite" value="" />
         </rule>        
      </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
```

This is working fine in normal flows. However when an error page(like 500 or 404) is rendered I am able to see the IIS version information.

I need to know how to handle this rewrite for error pages as well. Any suggestions would be appreciated